# CSS rules ignored after being added with jQuery addClass() in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, addclass

I have a form in which I use jQuery to hide / unhide  elements of a  element, depending on the selected value of another  element.

Everything works fine in all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) except in Safari 6.0

Here is my function that hides the  elements, depending on their value

```
function hideOptionIfValue(optionElements) {
    /* Loop through the possible values of value (using JS's arguments) */
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        /* Reference arguments[i] as value for further use in .each() */
        var value = arguments[i];

        $(optionElements).each(function(){
            if($(this).val() === value) {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }
```

I depending on the cases, I call this function like this:

```
hideOptionIfValue(optionElementsConcerned, 'valueToHide5');
```

or like that:

```
hideOptionIfValue(optionElementsConcerned, 'valueToHide1', 'valueToHide2', 'valueToHide3');
```

after setting this:

```
var optionElementsConcerned = $('#id1 option, #id2 option, #id3 option');
```

After some basic debugging, it looks like the problem comes from the "non-interpretation" of the css rules associated with the hidden class (from the html5 boilerplate):

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Actually, using the Inspector in Safari, the selected options do have the hidden class assigned to them, but they do appear in the drop down menu.